# Test for Upper Case - T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

All,

How can I check if a specified varchar character or entire string is upper case in T-Sql? Ideally I'd like to write a function to test if a character is upper case, then I can later apply that to a generic varchar. It should return false for non alphabetic characters. I am only interested in english language characters.

I am working with T-sql in SQL Management Studio, and I have tried pulling records beginning with a lower case letter from a table in this fashion:

```
select * from TABLE
where SUBSTRING(author,1,1) != LOWER(SUBSTRING(author,1,1))
```

Which returns 0 records, but I know there are records beginning with upper and lower case letters.

Thanks

---

**EDIT:** Since both [podiluska](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453411/podiluska) and [joachim-isaksoon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson) have successfully answered my question (Both methods work for my purposes), would someone mind explaining which would be the most efficient method to use to query a table with a large number of records to filter out records with authors beginning with or without a capital letter?

Comment: "Non alphabetic characters" in which language? Would it return true or false for `Π`? (upper case `π`)

Comment: Thanks Martin, I've improved my question. I don't mind what it returns for non english alphabet characters.

Comment: Answer to EDIT part: It should be irrelevant, both queries should perform the same. Either way you have to scan through your whole table and retrieve value of `author` for each row - which is what takes 99% of query time. Functions like `LOWER()`,`UNICODE()` are meaningless performance-wise and whichever you choose should not make a difference. With that said, I still suggest you test both queries on your actual data and see if either works better.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Using collations

eg:

```
if ('a'='A' Collate Latin1_General_CI_AI) 
    print'same 1'
else
    print 'different 1'

if ('a'='A' Collate Latin1_General_CS_AI) 
    print'same 2'
else
    print 'different 2'
```

The CS in the collation name indicates Case Sensitive (and CI, Case Insensitive). The AI/AS relates to accent sensitivity.

or in your example

```
SUBSTRING(author,1,1) <> LOWER(SUBSTRING(author,1,1)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
```

Answer (score 22):

To check if ch is upper case, and is a character that can be converted between upper and lower case (ie excluding non alphabetic characters);

```
WHERE UNICODE(ch) <> UNICODE(LOWER(ch))
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a79d/1);

Comment: @podiluska Indeed, but it's not very clear what to do with entire strings that _contain_ symbols anyway, so decided to solve the limited problem :)

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
declare @v varchar(10) = 'ABC', @ret int = 0
select @ret = 1 where upper(@v)=@v COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
select @ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Lower case letters have the same ASCII or UNICODE value as their upper-case version with the exception that lower case letters have a bit flag of 32 set.

This is very easy to detect directly, or to wrap the detection into User-defined functions like IsUpper() and IsLower().

Example (note that both ASCII() and UNICODE() work interchangeably here):

```
DECLARE @Letter char(1);

SET @Letter = 'A'
PRINT   
    @Letter + space(1) + 
    CASE
    WHEN (UNICODE(@Letter) & 32 > 0) THEN 'is lower case'
    ELSE 'is UPPER CASE'
    END

SET @Letter = 'z'
PRINT   
    @Letter + space(1) + 
    CASE
    WHEN (ASCII(@Letter) & 32 > 0) THEN 'is lower case'
    ELSE 'is UPPER CASE'
    END

-- Output:
--    A is UPPER CASE
--    z is lower case
```

This function will look for any upper case letters in an entire string using a recursive CTE:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ContainsUpper](@InputString [varchar](80))
RETURNS [bit] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result         bit     = 0,
            @LowerString    varchar(80) = lower(@InputString);

    WITH Letters
    AS
    (
        SELECT  Position    = 1,
                IsUpper     = 
                    CASE unicode(left(@InputString,1))
                    WHEN unicode(left(@LowerString,1)) THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                    END

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  Position    = Position + 1,
                IsUpper     = 
                    CASE unicode(substring(@InputString, Position + 1, 1))
                    WHEN unicode(substring(@LowerString, Position + 1, 1)) THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                    END
        FROM    Letters
        WHERE   Position < len(@InputString)
    )
    SELECT  @Result = max(convert(int, IsUpper))
    FROM    Letters

    RETURN @Result
END
```

Answer (score -1):

**3 easy steps to check string is uppercase or lowercase program in PL/SQL using both**

```
       1.Function 
       2.procedure
```

**using function**

step:1 there are two variable

step:2 one is to stored your string and the other is to convert your string into uppercase

step:3 the check condition if variable_one != variable_convert then it show
string is lowercase else show string is uppercase

```
set serveroutput on 
declare
        string_one varchar2(5);
        string_convert varchar2(5);
begin
        string_one:=&string;
        string_convert:=UPPER(string_one);
        if string_one != string_convert then
                dbms_output.put_line('string is lowercse');
        else
                dbms_output.put_line('string is UPPERCASE');
        end if;

end;
/
```

**using procedure**

> check string is an uppercase or lowercase program in pl/sql using
> procedure logic is the same but no need to declare a variable change

```
 set serveroutput on 
            create or replace procedure upper_cse(str_one varchar2)
        is
    begin
            if str_one != UPPER(str_one) then
                    dbms_output.put_line('string is lowercse');
            else
                    dbms_output.put_line('string is UPPERCASE');
            end if;
    end;
    /
```

Comment: OP asked for T-SQL, not PL/SQL