# SQL Return all upper case values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have fields with values of a mix of both Upper case and Lower Case characters.
I am trying to return just the Upper case values as one result and likewise return just the lower case values in another. I am not trying to convert one to the other, just return the current data as is.

I cant seem to find a statement to do this and "SUBSTRING" will only return the value I specify i.e. the first and last characters

So for example  if I have AAbbCCdd and want to return the upper case values, the result I need is AACC.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this in SQL -- there are easy ways to do it in front end languages.  Are you sure you need to do this on the server side?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Do you want to extract upper case letters from a single column?  Or do you want to return values where all the letters in a column are upper case?

Comment: @GordonLinoff he wants to extract

Comment: This is a pretty strange requirement. What could be the possible real world usage of such a thing? This is not easy (well not fast at least) in sql.

Comment: Do you want to `query` the `column` value and then handle the upper/lower-case thing in PHP or do you want a `query` that does the filtering for you?

Comment: @Hogan  Unfortunately yes, work requirement for work client. Sean My thoughts exactly, but the client wants what the client wants.

Comment: I think it could be done quite easily in Oracle with REGEXP_REPLACE, but it seems sql-server has no support for regular expressions.

Comment: @popovitsj not true - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx - but this is not easy but probably the way to solve this requirement.

Comment: @RST a query that does the filtering is the requirement. @ popovitsj Agreed, I have searched many a far for a simple expression to complete the same, but alas returned no result.

Comment: You're probably going to need to write a proc to do this. This post might help: [test-for-upper-case-t-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123655/test-for-upper-case-t-sql)

Answer (score 2):

With a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCased](@BUFFER VARCHAR(MAX), @GETUPPER BIT) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LEN INT = LEN(@BUFFER), @POS INT = 1, @CHAR CHAR(1), @RESULT VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    WHILE @POS <= @LEN BEGIN
        SET @CHAR = SUBSTRING(@BUFFER, @POS, 1)
        SET @RESULT += CASE WHEN @CHAR COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 
            CASE WHEN @GETUPPER = 1 THEN UPPER(@CHAR) ELSE LOWER(@CHAR) END COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN @CHAR ELSE '' END
        SET @POS += 1
    END
    RETURN @RESULT
END

... 

select
  dbo.GetCased('AAbbCCdd', 1) as 'all upper',
  dbo.GetCased('AAbbCCdd', 0) as 'all lower'
```

Or

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnRemovePatternFromString](@BUFFER VARCHAR(MAX), @PATTERN VARCHAR(128)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @POS INT = PATINDEX(@PATTERN, @BUFFER COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)
    WHILE @POS > 0 BEGIN
        SET @BUFFER = STUFF(@BUFFER, @POS, 1, '')
        SET @POS = PATINDEX(@PATTERN, @BUFFER COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)
    END
    RETURN @BUFFER
END

...

select
  dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString('AAbbCCdd ', '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%') as 'all lower'
  dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString('AAbbCCdd ', '%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%') as 'all upper'
```

(Cannot use [a-z])

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].returnUppers
    (
      @str AS varchar(Max)
    )
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @len INT
        DECLARE @cc INT = 1
        DECLARE @return VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

        SELECT @len = LEN(@str)

        WHILE @len >= @cc
            BEGIN
                IF UPPER(SUBSTRING(@str,@cc,1)) = SUBSTRING(@str,@cc,1) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
                    SELECT @return = @return + SUBSTRING(@str,@cc,1)
                SET @cc += 1
            END

        RETURN @return
    END
GO
```

To use:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(20) = 'AAbbCCdd'
SELECT dbo.returnUppers(@string)
```

Returns AACC.  You need to write a similar function for lowers just change UPPER() to LOWER()

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in the comments - this should really be done in the presentation layer, not in SQL.

However, that doesn't stop it being a bit of fun!

The key is to use a case-sensitive collation. In this example I've gone for *SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_**CS**_AS* (the "CS" = CaseSensitive. "CI" = CaseInsensitive)

You're never going to get good performance with this kind of thing though as the solution involves looping (recursive CTE in this case)

```
DECLARE @t table (
   a char(10)
);

INSERT INTO @t (a)
  VALUES ('AbC')
       , ('ABCDEFGHIJ')
       , ('aBCdEFghij')
       , ('AbcdefhhiJ')
       , ('ABcdEFGhij')
;

--SELECT a
--     , a COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS As case_sensitive_collation
--     , Replace(a COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 'A', '#') As case_sensitive_replace
--FROM   @t
--;

; WITH characters_to_replace AS (
  SELECT number
       , Char(number) As c
       , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY number) As sequence
  FROM   dbo.numbers
  WHERE  number BETWEEN 1 AND 255 -- basic characters
  AND    number NOT BETWEEN 65 AND 90 -- Exclude capital A-Z
)
, replacements AS (
SELECT a As original_value
     , Cast(a COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS As nvarchar(max)) As new_value
     , Cast(0 As bigint) As sequence
FROM   @t

  UNION ALL

    SELECT replacements.original_value
         , Cast(Replace(replacements.new_value, characters_to_replace.c, '') As nvarchar(max))
         , characters_to_replace.sequence
    FROM   replacements
     INNER
      JOIN characters_to_replace
        ON characters_to_replace.sequence = replacements.sequence + 1
)
SELECT original_value
     , new_value
FROM   replacements
WHERE  sequence = (SELECT Max(sequence) FROM characters_to_replace)
OPTION (MaxRecursion 255)
;
```