# How to delete a row repeat in sql with a column in uppercase?

Tags: sql

Got rows equals, but the only difference is a column when one of this columns have the same string but in upper case like:

column:channel
data: hello

column:channel
data: HELLO

i need to delete the rows with the upper case

Thanks

Comment: sql-server ?  oracle ?  which db?

Comment: Do you want to delete all records with all characters in upper case?  If so see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123655/test-for-upper-case-t-sql

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server**

To remove all lines with the `data` string fully uppercase:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (
    data NVARCHAR(120)
)

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('HELLO');
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('hello');

SELECT * FROM @T1;

DELETE FROM @T1 
WHERE data COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS IN (
    SELECT UPPER(data) AS d FROM @T1 GROUP BY data
); 

SELECT * FROM @T1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your need, this could be a solution in **Oracle**:

Setup:

```
SQL> create table dupTable(someField, someOtherField ) as (
  2    select 'hello', 'something' from dual union all
  3    select 'HELLO', 'something' from dual union all
  4    select 'HELLO', 'something else' from dual union all
  5    select 'bye', 'something' from dual union all
  6    select 'bye', 'something else' from dual
  7  )
  8  /
```

Data before deletion:

```
SQL> select * from dupTable;

SOMEF SOMEOTHERFIELD
----- --------------
hello something
HELLO something
HELLO something else
bye   something
bye   something else
```

Delete:

```
SQL> delete from dupTable d
  2  where exists ( select 1
  3                 from dupTable d2
  4                 where d2.someField = lower(d.someField)
  5                   and d2.someField != d.someField
  6                   and d2.someOtherField = d.someOtherField
  7               );

1 row deleted.
```

Final result:

```
SQL> select * from dupTable;

SOMEF SOMEOTHERFIELD
----- --------------
hello something
HELLO something else
bye   something
bye   something else

SQL>
```